# fix an absolute div inside a scrolling div

Tags: html, css

**HTML code**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="normal">
    a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a...
    </div>
    <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.parent {
    width:170px; height:300px; border:1px solid #000; 
    overflow:auto; position:relative;
 }
.normal {}
.abs {
    height:40px; position:absolute; bottom:0; 
    background-color:gray; width:100%;
 }
```

How do I fix the `.abs` div to the bottom of `.parent` div?

Comment: By Fixed, do you want it to stick it at the end of the div and all the items should scroll above it??

Comment: Would something like this work? http://jsfiddle.net/GPJPq/

Comment: should be fixed at the bottom and all the contents behind it.

Comment: ok @MotaBOS - [Here is the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532796/fix-an-absolute-div-inside-a-scrolling-div/18532983#18532983)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want:

Your original **HTML** was this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="normal">
    a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a ... a<br />a<br />bottom
    </div>
    <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

and for your **CSS**, try this:

```
.parent {
    width:170px;
    height: 340px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative
}
.normal {
    overflow:auto;
    height: 300px;
}
.abs {
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(123, 123, 123, 0.4);
}
```

You want the text to scroll, so set `overflow: auto` to the `.normal` block container.

Your `.parent` has a fixed height, so adjust the height of `.normal` to be the overall height minus that of the `.abs` element.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EbFXR/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="normal">
        a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
        <div class="abs"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {width:170px; height:300px; border:1px solid #000; overflow:auto; position:relative}
.normal { position:relative; padding-bottom: 40px; }
.abs {height:40px; position:absolute; bottom:0; background-color:gray; width:100%}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Ymb/4/)

Comment: Some of the content is actually being masked by the `.abs` div... you need a bottom margin or padding some place.... see demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/L4Ymb/1/

Comment: I cannot put `.abs` inside `.normal`. I have limitations such as at one point of time I am replacing all the contents of `.normal`

Comment: @MotaBOS, It's unclear what you are asking, there are multiple different answers doing different things here. Do you always want the grey div to be FIXED at the bottom of the container, while content scrolls behind, or you simply want it at the end of the previous element that grows?

Comment: He has mentioned that it _should be fixed at the bottom and all the contents behind it_ - @plalx

Comment: @MotaBOS Please tell me if the content should be behind the `abs` div, or it should be above it

Comment: contents should flow behind .abs but when the content ends (scrolling end) it should end above .abs. which we can do by giving bottom padding to .normal I think.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the parent div to

```
position:relative;
```

Or correct me if I'am wrong.